# Swagger not functioning when run through APIGEE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, swagger-ui, apigee

I've got an ASP.NET Web API Core 2 project, that uses `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` nuget to add swagger UI to my solution. 
When I run this in debugger or hosting it in IIS, swagger UI comes up nicely and it all works as expected.

But when I put a proxy for my web site into APIGEE, it comes up with

> Fetch error Not Found /swagger/v1/swagger.json

Here are the relevant pieces of my project

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info {
        Version = "v1",
            Title = "My Web API",
            Description = "An awesome API.",
            TermsOfService = "",
            Contact = new Contact {
                Name = "...",
                    Email = "...",
                    Url = "http://..."
            }
    });
});
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => { c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath("Project1.xml")); });
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => { c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath("Project2.xml")); });
```

and

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My Web API v1"); });
```

How can I enable swagger to work when its run through APIGEE?

**UPDATE**
The debug console shows an error.

> HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the
>   requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
>   (XHR) GET - https://mysite.apigee.net/swagger/v1/swagger.json

It has dropped the site path completely. When I added

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My Web API v1"); });
```

it swagger UI comes up, but the calls it can make are now dropping the site prefix. For example,

`https://mysite.apigee.net/myapp/about` becomes `https://mysite.apigee.net/about`

What should happen is

`https://mysite.apigee.net/myapp/swagger` brings up the swagger ui
`https://mysite.apigee.net/myapp/swagger/v1/swagger.json` gets me the JSON
`https://mysite.apigee.net/myapp/about` calls my normal endpoints.

Its only the first that doesnt work, which looks in the wrong place.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the swagger using the `{apigeehost}/{basepath }/swagger`?

Comment: I am not sure what my base path is. I have tried `{apigeehost}/swagger` and that gives me the above error.

Comment: Does your other endpoints api endpoints work if accessed directly e.g. GET requests?

Comment: Yes, all other endpoints work as expected.

Comment: Furthermore, accessing the json directly works as expected again. So its literally the UI that cannot find it.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue.  You need to add your Apigee base path to the Swagger Endpoint.  In this example "myapp" is the base path.  I also had to do a Ctrl + F5 on my Chrome browser to reload the page to see the change.

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { c.SwaggerEndpoint("/myapp/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My Web API v1"); });
```